# Piranha CMS - Anchor Link and Sitemap question

Tags: piranha-cms

I am creating a website with the CMS, and like to do the following.

1. Add the anchor link to the toolbar so I can make links to the content with same page, i have tried both

`"toolbar": "bold italic | bullist numlist hr | alignleft aligncenter alignright | formatselect styleselect | piranhalink piranhaimage anchor",`

and

`toolbar": "bold italic | bullist numlist hr | alignleft aligncenter alignright | formatselect styleselect | piranhalink piranhaimage piranhaanchor",`

and neither of them seem to work.

2. Also after I add all my pages, is there a way i can have access to a sitemap so I can submit to google.
3. If I were to inject google adsense into my pages in the future, what route would I take so they are added to all pages, or do I have to modify each page content?